# How do I map a complex object to DataWeave fixed width format

Tags: mule, fixed-width, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I have a JSON Object

```
{
   "collection": [
      { 
         "field1": "1111",
         "field2": "1122"
      },
      { 
         "field1": "2211",
         "field2": "2222"
      }
   ],
   "otherObject": {
      "otherField": "3333"
   }
}
```

I would like to have this output :

> s01>1111~~~~~~1122~~~~~~
>
> s01>2211~~~~~~2222~~~~~~
>
> s02>3333~~~~~~

So i used this transformation :

```
%dw 1.0
%output text/plain structureIdent = "response" , schemaPath = "response.ffd"

---
{
    collection: payload.collection map ({
        field1: $.field1,
        field2: $.field2
    }),
    otherObject: {
        otherField: payload.otherObject.otherField
    }
}
```

and my *response.ffd* is like this

```
  form: FIXEDWIDTH
  structures:
  - id: 'response'
    name: response
    tagStart: 0
    data:
    - { idRef: 'collection', count: '>1'}
    - { idRef: 'otherObject', count: 1 }
  segments:
  - id: 'collection'
    name: collection
    tag: 's01>'
    values:
    - { name: 'field1', type: String, length: 10 }
    - { name: 'field2', type: String, length: 10 }
  - id: 'otherObject'
    name: otherObject
    tag: 's02>'
    values:
    - { name: 'otherField', type: String, length: 10 }
```

But i'm getting this result

```
s02>3333~~~~~~
```

as if *dataweave* doesn't know about my array, What should i do to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the DataWeave code with the following example:

```
%dw 1.0
%output text/plain structureIdent = "response" , schemaPath = "response.ffd"
---
{
    collection: flatten [payload.collection map ({
        field1: $.field1,
        field2: $.field2
    })],
    otherObject: {
        otherField: payload.otherObject.otherField
    }
}
```

1. Ensure the collection is an Array by adding a bracket: `[ ... map ...]`
2. Remove the additional bracket using `flatten`, because the `map` itself already return an Array

Although it returns the same result, somehow DataWeave treats it differently as if the data structure is written manually: e.g.:

```
collection: [{
    field1: payload.collection.field1[0],
    field2: payload.collection.field2[0]
},{
    field1: payload.collection.field1[1],
    field2: payload.collection.field2[1]
}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked like a charm !
However, That is not a solution we could find in the dataweave documentation :)